# PDO row doesn't exist?

Tags: pdo

Below is my code:

```
<?php

$url = $_GET['url'];
$wordlist = array("Www.", "Http://", "Http://www.");
foreach ($wordlist as &$word) {
    $word = '/\b' . preg_quote($word, '/') . '\b/';
}
$url = preg_replace($wordlist, '', $url);
?>
<?php
$oDB = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mcnsaoia_onsafe;host=localhost;charset=utf8', 'mcnsaoia_xx', 'PASSWORD');
$hStmt=$oDB->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE hjemmside = :hjemmside AND godkendt=ja");
$hStmt->execute(array('hjemmside' => $url));

if( $row = $hStmt->fetch() ){
    echo "EXIST";
}else{
    echo "NOT EXIST";
}


?>
```

My problem is that it says NOT EXIST, because I know that there is a row which should be found with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE hjemmside = :hjemmside AND godkendt=ja
```

So why does it say not exist? I have absolutely no idea :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should surround with quotes your not integer variable in your query

```
AND godkendt='ja'
```

Or maybe let pdo deal with it

```
$hStmt=$oDB->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE hjemmside = :hjemmside AND godkendt = :ja");
$hStmt->execute(array(':hjemmside' => $url, ':ja' => 'ja'));
                     //^ i added : for placeholder here, you missed it
```

I would also rather check if rows are returned

```
if($hStmt->$eowVount() > 0){
    $row = $hStmt->fetch()
    echo "EXIST";
}else{
    echo "NOT EXIST";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$hStmt=$oDB->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE hjemmside = :hjemmside
  AND godkendt=ja");
```

try

```
$hStmt=$oDB->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE hjemmside = :hjemmside
  AND godkendt='ja'");
```

The left is most likely a column and the right side is a string? I don't speak your language, but this is the first thing coming to my mind.

Comment: You are sharp :-) Thanks